# Stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion

SharePointians of StackExchange,

You might have noticed my absence over the past few months.. which is mostly due to me not doing much SharePoint anymore. My job also has expanded to the point where I don't have a lot of time to spend on my moderator duties so I am stepping down as a moderator.

I came on as a mod pro tem when SharePoint.SE graduated [from Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint) three years ago and have seen a ton of great SharePoint questions asked/answered.

The site has been in good hands since our last election and I'm confident our current mods can continue to make SP.SE a great resource.  I can definitely appreciate all of the hard work they put into making the site great. :)

So long and thanks for all the fish!

Comment: Thank you for your three years of service!

Comment: Sad to see you go, good luck in the java-land ;)

Comment: Thanks, Kit. It's been a pleasure working with you. I agree that we got a great set of replacement moderators at the last election.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions to the SharePoint community, Kit!

Comment: Thank you Kit :)

Comment: Good luck and ty!

Comment: Good Luck, I think its good and brave decision.

Answer (score 11):

## Don’t Panic!

You have made an incredible effort over the three years here Kit, and you are a guiding light to those hanging in here. If I browse through Meta, you have answered a quarter of every asked question, which says it all really. Apart from Meta, you have also provided 136 really useful answers where my favorite is the answer on the question [Creating a workflow to be run by a timer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/41943/6382).

I hope you’ll pop in to say hi once in a while when you have a minute. I’ll see too that you can have an open channel into our room (when it’s not automatically frozen by Vogons).

[image]

Good luck on your new assignment, and if you ever feel the need for a good SharePoint answer, you know where to find it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks Benny! :)

Comment: I would flag above comment as too chatty :P

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Tempting, but the powers would decline your flag ;)

Comment: Biased decisions :D